# Options to run python script in azure to get data from streaming API

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, http-live-streaming

We developed a python script which reads data from a streaming API and we want this script to be in active always in Azure environment. What are serverless(similar to azure function) options available to run this script?

Comment: Hi sandeep If the two options I provided below are helpful to your requirement, please accept it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned azure function, you can just deploy your python on azure function. If you want it always in active, you can enable `Always on` setting in "Configuration" --> "General settings".

Or you can also [create a webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) in app service and deploy your python code to it.